# Function/Formula that sorts a comma seperated list alphabetically/ascending order

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, formula

Example, ONE cell I have has the value:

```
1133,1131,1141,1142,1143,1151,1132,1181
```

How do I get this going in ascending order?

```
1131,1132,1133,1141,1142,1143,1151,1181
```

Doing this to work with a lot of different things so hoping to find a formula or vba function driven solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Function sortingHat(str As String, _
                    Optional delim As String = ",")
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, arr As Variant, tmp As Variant

    'split the string into an array
    arr = Split(str, delim)

    'sort the array
    For a = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For b = a + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(b) < arr(a) Then
                tmp = arr(a)
                arr(a) = arr(b)
                arr(b) = tmp
            End If
        Next b
    Next a

    'join the array into a string
    sortingHat = Join(arr, delim)
End Function
```

[image: sortingHat]

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Function MySort(txt As String, Sep As String) As String

    Dim a

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For Each a In Split(txt, Sep)
            .Add Trim$(CStr(a))
        Next
        .Sort
        MySort = Join(.ToArray, Sep)
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

As requested in your title, the function performs an *alphabetic* sort rather than a *numerical* sort.